# Converting datetime string to (float) timestamp in C++

Tags: c++, timestamp

Consider the following code as an attempt to convert a string datetime `"23/08/1999 23:23:23"` to a float type variable

```
std::string datetime = "23/08/1999 23:23:23";
const char* format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S";
std::string s{ datetime };
std::tm t{};
std::istringstream ss(s);
ss >> std::get_time(&t, format);
std::time_t timestamp = mktime(&t);
```

The *`static_cast`* method seems to work when converting from *`time_t`* to *`long int`*:

```
long int tm = static_cast<long int> (timestamp);
```

but with *`float`* as type *`static_cast`* method faces loss of data. Is there any possible way to cast *`time_t`* to *`float`* or to directly convert *`std::string datetime`* to a *`float`* type variable?

Comment: The loss of data is inevitable. It happens because `float` can represent fewer integral values than `time_t`. No amount of casting can change the values that a type can hold.

Comment: Is there some `floating point` type that can represent `time_t`?

Comment: Assuming a `time_t` is 32 bits then a `double` would be enough (it has 53 bits for the mantissa). But if `time_t` is 64 bits then I don't think so.

Comment: I assume it is 64 bites since *935447003* is been converted to *9.35447e+08*.

Comment: 935447003 is a <32 bit integer, so it should convert exactly. Don't confuse how a double prints with how it is represented internally. To be certain print the value of `sizeof(time_t)`, if that is 4 then it is 32 bit, if it is 8 then it's 64 bits.

Comment: Both `time_t` and `double` are 8 bytes (looking with `sizeof`). I forgot that I could look in memory with debug and I can confirm that with double there is no loss of data (unlike float with 4 bytes), a priori from what the console was printing. Thanks!

Comment: Note that ```time_t``` being 32 bit will soon end (if it hasn't already on your platform) because it will overflow in 2038. Just google "Year 2038 problem". However, ```double``` should be okay for the foreseeable future because even 64 bit ```time_t``` will not use the upper bits anytime soon, so conversion back to int remains safe.

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks for the advise, indeed I was curious about the dependencies of the size in time_t.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a floating point representation without loss of data you can use a double instead of a float. Although not all long int can be stored in a double without loss of precision, for the number of seconds (and probably microseconds) since the epoch, a double should be adequate. But you should check the bounds of the values you are processing and also that you have enough precision left for you needs. Check out a tutorial on the behaviour and limitations of floating point numbers for more information.

Another alternative, which may be useful depending on the details of your requirements, is to pick a recent date in the past and calculate the difference between the input date and that point in time and store that, such that the result can be contained in a float comfortably.

Finally if you really need to process this without any loss of precision, you can use an arbitrary precision maths library such as https://gmplib.org/ (note I have not tried this library myself, but it won't be the only one available).